# Проблема с focus. Скрытые элементы

Tags: html, css, display, focus

Если попытаться нажать на кнопку под текстом, то теряется фокус с элемента и она просто пропадает.

Как можно подправить? Очень уж не охота переписывать всю секцию.

```css
#title #tech:focus ~ #techText,
#title #diagramm:focus ~ #diagrammText,
#title #circle:focus ~ #circleText,
#title #loope:focus ~ #loopeText{
 display: block !important;
}
.serviceContent{ 
 width: 60%;
 height: 50%;
 display: none;
 float: right; 
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
    left: 30%;
    right: 20px;
    top: 0;    
}
```

```html
                                      
<div id="title">
   <div class="miniMenu">
  <div tabindex="0" class="icons" id="diagramm">
     <img src="img\service\diagramm.png" alt="diagramm">
  </div>
  <div tabindex="0" class="icons" id="tech">
     <img src="img\service\tech.png" alt="tech">
  </div>
  <div tabindex="0" class="icons" id="loope">
     <img src="img\service\loope.png" alt="loope">
  </div>
  <div tabindex="0" class="icons" id="circle">
     <img src="img\service\diagramm.png" alt="circle">
  </div>
  <div class="serviceContent" id="diagrammText">
     <p class="text" id="head">1Modern App Design</p>
     <img id="orangeUndrLine" src="img\service\line.png" alt="orange_undr_line">
     <p class="text" id="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas accusamus odio nulla ut iure quos beatae earum molestiae, aperiam nihil ex reprehenderit mollitia rem voluptatem, in odit nostrum atque, distinctio.</p>
     <div id="win" style="display:none;">
        <div class="overlay"></div>
        <div class="visible">
           <h2>Заголовок окна</h2>
           <div class="content">
              <p>Содержание</p>
              <p>Модальное окно фиксированной ширины</p>
           </div>
           <button type="button" onClick="getElementById('win').style.display='none';">закрыть</button>
        </div>
     </div>
     <button id="knowMoreBtn" type="button" onClick="getElementById('win').removeAttribute('style');">Know more</button>
  </div>
  <div class="serviceContent" id="techText">
     <p class="text" id="head">2Modern App Design</p>
     <img id="orangeUndrLine" src="img\service\line.png" alt="orange_undr_line">
     <p class="text" id="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas accusamus odio nulla ut iure quos beatae earum molestiae, aperiam nihil ex reprehenderit mollitia rem voluptatem, in odit nostrum atque, distinctio.</p>
     <button id="knowMoreBtn">Know more</button>
  </div>
  <div class="serviceContent" id="loopeText">
     <p class="text" id="head">3Modern App Design</p>
     <img id="orangeUndrLine" src="img\service\line.png" alt="orange_undr_line">
     <p class="text" id="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas accusamus odio nulla ut iure quos beatae earum molestiae, aperiam nihil ex reprehenderit mollitia rem voluptatem, in odit nostrum atque, distinctio.</p>
     <button id="knowMoreBtn">Know more</button>
  </div>
  <div class="serviceContent" id="circleText">
     <p class="text" id="head">4Modern App Design</p>
     <img id="orangeUndrLine" src="img\service\line.png" alt="orange_undr_line">
     <p class="text" id="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas accusamus odio nulla ut iure quos beatae earum molestiae, aperiam nihil ex reprehenderit mollitia rem voluptatem, in odit nostrum atque, distinctio.</p>
     <button id="knowMoreBtn">Know more</button>
  </div>
   </div>
   <div class="serviceImage">
  <img src="img\apple-watch-mockup.png" alt="">
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Элемент, который вы вызываете при событии `focus`, должен находится рядом с элементом-родителем. Вот пример:

https://codepen.io/LenskyUser/pen/RgaGGV

```css
.taber{
  width:100%;
}
.tab{
  width:50%;
  margin:auto;
  float:right;
  display:none;
  text-align:center;
}
.tab p{
  width:50%;
  margin:auto;
}
button{
  pointer-events:none;
}

.taber:focus{
  border:none;
  outline:none;
}
.taber:focus .tab {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="taber" tabindex="-1">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x50">
  
  <div class="tab">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x200">
    <h2>lorem Ipsum</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat,  At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,  no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.  Stet clita kasd gubergren,  no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.  no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.  no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.  sed diam voluptua.  
    </p>
    <button>Смотреть</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="taber" tabindex="-1">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x50">
  
  <div class="tab">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/390x240">
    <h2>lorem Ipsum</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat,  At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,  no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.  Stet clita kasd gubergren,  no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.  no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.  no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.  sed diam voluptua.  
    </p>
    <button>Смотреть</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="taber" tabindex="-1">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x50">
  
  <div class="tab">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/220x340">
    <h2>lorem Ipsum</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat,  At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,  no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.  Stet clita kasd gubergren,  no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.  no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.  no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.  sed diam voluptua.  
    </p>
    <button>Смотреть</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Допустим, это как вариант. Суть проблемы, насколько я понимаю, это не решает. При потере фокуса он все равно закрывается не обрабатывая нажатие кнопки.

Comment: так я же для кнопки отключил события `pointer-events:none;`

Comment: так ведь весь вопрос в том, чтоб она нажималась и не скрывалась при попытке нажать.